# Why is my Galaxy Nexus always force quit every apps or page I'm currently on?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

Lately my phone have been force quitting out of any apps or pages I'm currently on and i have no idea what is causing it. I did recentl update to android 4.2, I'm not sure if that is the reason for causing the problem.

Comment: Is it for all the apps? Or for some specific apps? If not for all the apps, you can try clearing data for the apps that are crashing.

Answer (score 1):

It also happened to me after 4.2.1 updates. I just reset to factory settings. Now, it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted and custom clockworkmod installed then go to recovery mod and fix permissions will clear this issue..

Or you can use **[Rom Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en)** to fix permissions.